# Confused about organization chart and organization browser

Tags: 2013, organization-browser

The one that we have in MySite, is it called Organization Browser?
And the one we add as a web part in publishing site page, is it called Organization Chart?

What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Organizational Chart is a non browseable chart represented like a classic hierarchical tree. The Organizational Browser in MySite can be browsed if the Silverlight view is turned on and supported.

Read more: [Use SharePoint to Build an Org Chart](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Use-SharePoint-to-Build-an-Org-Chart-The-Options.aspx)